# Can you explain chunked encoding?

Tags: http, chunked-encoding

```
header("Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
echo"32
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
0
"; flush();exit;
```

When requested with Firefox, `32` and `0` are missing. Why?

Comment: Have you tried removing the flush.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [chunked transfer encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1) is a sequence of chunks where each chunk consists of at least a size indicator and the chunk data.

In this case `32` and `0` are the size indicators in hexadecimal notation that denote the length of the following chunk data. A chunk size of 0 denotes the end of the chunked data stream.

Comment: +1 Here is a fairly decent explanation too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding