# The last number in web response from netcat

Tags: http, response, netcat

What are the numbers that come before and after the response body?

Sometimes I get the last number and sometimes I do not.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Jan 2021 00:01:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: 0

16 <-------------------- this number
API Version 1.0 <------- the actual response body
0  <-------------------- and this number
```

The request was:

```
printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:HOST\r\n\r\n' | nc -i 3 -v HOST 80
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you explain chunked encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829145/can-you-explain-chunked-encoding)

Comment: Thank you! That definitely helped.

Answer (score 1):

It's the "chunked" transfer encoding. Details in RFC 7230, Section 4.1 (https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#chunked.encoding).

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was faster to ask on this site. Thank you!